# JSP pass setProperty into a java class with bean

Tags: java, jsp

How can i use session.getAttribute in some java class which is not a servlet .Something like this maybe or some other trick?

```
<%    
    <jsp:useBean id="bean" class="ProfitBean" scope="application"/>
        <jsp:setProperty name="bean" value='<%=session.getAttribute("idUser")%>'/>
    %>

    public class ProfitBean{
    private int idUser;
    public void setIdUser(int IdUser){
    ...
    }
    public int getIdUser(){
    ...
    }
    }



    public class SomeClass{
    public void doSomething(){
    ProfitBean pb =new ProfitBean
    int userId = pb.getIdUser();

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A session need a Request. So the request must deliver the userId to your Application-Scope-ProfitBean.

You can use the Singleton antipattern in this case, so the ProfitBean.getInstance().get/setIdUser() will contain the same values.

```
private static ProfitBean profitBeanInstance;

@Deprecated
public ProfitBean(){
    profitBeanInstance=this;
}

public static ProfitBean getInstance(){
    if (profitBeanInstance == null) {
        NullPointerException cause = new NullPointerException();
        throw new IllegalStateException("The instance has not been created by blabla.jsp!", cause);
    }
    return profitBeanInstance;
}
```

**WARNING:** This Singleton will be available for any User. In "SomeClass" you cant ensure what user set this value.

Comment: I admit that the question is almost unintelligible, but I'm not sure how this answer makes sense. That's honestly said a terrible piece of code.

Comment: Be more creative BalusC, if i could be helpfully in this case i am lucky.

Answer (score 0):

If the class can't get it, it should ask for it.

In other words, just pass the desired value to it while invoking the method.

```
someClass.doSomething(session.getAttribute("idUser"));
```

Or, depending on the context.

```
someClass.doSomething(profitBean);
```